# How do I split the values in Python list at regular intervals?

Tags: python, list

Here's a list like this.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I want to split this list every 4 intervals.

In other words, I want to make it like this.

> [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]

I want to divide the list and save it.

Is there a function that provides this partitioning capability?

Comment: `newlist = [mylist[i * len(mylist) // 3: (i + 1) * len(mylist) // 3] for i in range(3)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
  if(i+1)%4 == 0:
    print(mylist[i-3:i+1])
```

Comment: very very thanks you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `iter` like this, to split the list into sublists

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> list(zip(*([iter(mylist)]*4)))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12)]
>>> 
>>> list(map(list, zip(*([iter(mylist)]*4))))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```